# C++: Getting an string input through char*

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I am completely confused about a taking an string input in C++.

```
char str[4];
cin>>str;
cout<<str;
```

works. but the

```
char* str;
cin>>str;
cout<<str;
```

doesn't work.
why?

Comment: you mean that by `str=new char[4];` the problem will be solved.

Comment: yes, but you'll have more problems, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jean-François Fabre said you can use `std::string` to achieve your goal.

Just in case you wanted to use pure C syntax and char arrays (with a fixed size N - in your case 3) you might go with something like that:

```
#define N 3
char str[N + 1];
fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
```

This makes sure that you won't encounter an overflow.

Answer (score 6):

because in the second case, no memory is allocated: you're writing to undefined memory area => UB (likely: SEGV)

You could do `str=new char[4];`, but if you input more than 3 characters you have a buffer overflow problem as well, and since you cannot control what the user inputs, you cannot ensure that it won't happen.

(could also happen in your first working case of course)

So, since you're using C++, I'd suggest to use `std::string` like this:

```
std::string str;
cin>>str;
cout<<str;
```

no more `char *` or arrays, no more allocation, memory leaks...: real C++. You can still get the `const char *` representation of the object using `str.c_str()` when you want to interface with C functions.

You can also concatenate `string` objects like this: `a + b`, as opposed to the dreaded `strcat`, and the list goes on and on...

I could dabble for hours on how `string` is better than `char`, or I could link to other answers like those:

- [std::string vs. char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672346/stdstring-vs-char)
- [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Comment: you mean that `str=new char[4];` will solve my problem?

Comment: would solve your _immediate_ problem. But please don't use char arrays, you've got C++ power, use it.

Comment: @Bob__ already started, but I don't want to explain it in a mediocre way. Looking for a SO post.